# store specific object arrays from JSON in string var

Tags: javascript, json, string, ecmascript-6

```
  fetch('https://www.website.com/json-data/obj/v3/options/options')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    const populate = document.getElementById('populate');    
    if (typeof(populate) != 'undefined' && populate != null)
    {
      populate.innerHTML = myJson.obj['some_data99'];

      SpecificDataCopy = myJson.obj['some_data99'].toString();

      String.prototype.breakAt = function(breakAt) {
        return this.substr(0,breakAt) + '<br/>' + this.substr(breakAt);
      };
      SpecificDataCopy.breakAt(268); 
    }
```

I have tried the above recently, but continues to error '`SpecificDataCopy`' is not defined.

I have also tried this:

```
  String.SpecificDataCopy = myJson.obj['some_data99'].toString();
```

I am trying to store this part of json response; `myJson.obj['some_data99']` as a string variable; so I can inject a `<br>` tag in that text at a specific certain point. *i.e.* character `268`

Comment: what is  myJson.obj['some_data99'] show your console or data which is storing in  myJson.obj['some_data99']

Comment: As you can see in this codepen, your code works fine, provided that the data you're trying to access actually exists (which we can't debug for you not seeing the rest of your code): https://codepen.io/Connum/pen/vYBbvVd?editors=1111

Comment: I also don't get what you're trying to achieve setting the string as a property of JavaScript's internal `String` object.

Comment: You are probably in strict mode. So you need to declare SpecificDataCopy first. Try changing to var SpecificDataCopy = myJson.obj['some_data99'].toString();
Also you can move String.prototype.breakAt to somewhere outside of promise handler. Need not reinitialize prototype everytime as it doesnt use any closure scope

Comment: Where's your `json` structure?

Comment: @nithin; thanks no more errors with your suggestion - however the on page text is not getting the <br> tag; should I rearrange my populate.innerHTML ?

Comment: The modified string is still hanging around :). You need to add it to populate.innerHTML = SpecificDataCopy.breakAt(268);

Comment: I will post a modified version as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably change the code like this.

```js
//Somewhere at the top
String.prototype.breakAt = function(breakAt) {
  return this.substr(0,breakAt) + '<br/>' + this.substr(breakAt);
};

 fetch('https://www.website.com/json-data/obj/v3/options/options')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    const populate = document.getElementById('populate');    
    if (typeof(populate) != 'undefined' && populate != null)
    {
      populate.innerHTML = myJson.obj['some_data99'].toString().breakAt(268);
    }
})
```